# .NET DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-3.5

I’m currently trying to use this control to provide a means of selecting a date and time from a dialog box.  However, I can’t seem to work out how to allow selection of a date AND time (format seems to allow short, long, custom and time).  Please could someone point me to the relevant property for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a custom format which includes the time, then it can all be edited. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form {
            Controls = { 
                new DateTimePicker {
                    Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom,
                    CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                }
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Note that the time part has to be entered using the keyboard in this case - clicking on the dropdown displays a calendar allowing the date to be set, but I don't believe there's an equivalent for the time.

EDIT: Note that if you use `ShowUpDown = true` this does indeed let you do everything with the mouse - but it means you lose the ability to pick the date in a simple visual way. I think as a user, I'd prefer to just do the time bits with a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Set the picker format to Custom, and then set the [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) property to fit what you want to use.

I'm not sure about whether you can pick times by default, but if you set the [ShowUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showupdown.aspx) property to True, you should be able to pick pretty much anything using the spin boxes.  That probably will disable the calendar, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Windows Forms, that doesn't seem to be possible.
You could of course set the `CustomFormat` property to include time, but you can't select both date and time via the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I think to solve your problem, you habe to use two DateTimePicker. One for the date and one for the time.

One little example from the msdn

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Or you use one dtp and do this

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

and setting up dtp

```
this.dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

so you have only one dtp.